parsing long character string into separate rows with data.table fails
I have a dataset which contains a column with separate entries as a character string (a CLOB in the original oracle database). Using a tidyverse approach, strsplit, unnest and str_extract work well, with a very limited subset of the original data. Expanding the dataset leads to my computer crashing.
I have tried to use a data.table approach, since in my experience, data.table is better when working with large datasets, and this works fine with example data. But it fails with the real data unfortunately. See example data and code below. Error message (which I can't reproduce with my example data) is:

Error in [.data.table(mondata_dt, , strsplit(CLOB, "\r\n"), by = .(ID,  :
j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group

DATA:
library(tidyverse); library(data.table)

ID <- c(1,2)
DEVICE <- c(50,50)
METHOD <- c(12,12)
CLOB <- c("[02.01.2024 07:39:30]144,00\r\n[02.01.2024 07:41:30]146,00\r\n[02.01.2024 07:44:00]142,00\r\n[02.01.2024 07:49:00]167,00\r\n",
            "[02.01.2024 09:06:14]105,00\r\n[02.01.2024 09:07:44]107,00\r\n[02.01.2024 09:09:44]71,00\r\n[02.01.2024 09:11:44]86,00\r\n")
df <- data_frame(ID, DEVICE, METHOD, CLOB)

TIDYVERSE APPROACH:
df <- df %>% mutate(Extr=strsplit(CLOB, "\r\n")) %>% unnest(Extr) %>% select(-CLOB)
df <- df %>% mutate(DTTM=str_extract(Extr, "\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}"), VALUE=str_extract(Extr, "](.*)", group = 1))

DATA.TABLE APPROACH
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt <- dt[, strsplit(CLOB, "\r\n"), by = .(ID, DEVICE, METHOD)]
dt <- dt[, DTTM:=str_extract(V1, "\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}")]
dt <- dt[, VALUE:=str_extract(V1, "](.*)", group = 1)]


Possibly you have multiple rows with the same .(ID, DEVICE, METHOD). Try wrapping strsplit with unlist?

thanks everyone for your answers! I'll have access to the real data next week... I'll report on my success then ;-)

You possibly have multiple rows with the same .(ID, DEVICE, METHOD). Try wrapping strsplit with unlist. Demonstrating:
dt <- as.data.table(df[c(1, 1:2),])

This replicates your error:
dt[, strsplit(CLOB, "\r\n"), by = .(ID, DEVICE, METHOD)][
  ,DTTM:=str_extract(V1, "\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}")
][, VALUE := str_extract(V1, "](.*)", group = 1)][]
#> Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , strsplit(CLOB, "\r\n"), by = .(ID, DEVICE, : j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group

Wrapping strsplit with unlist:
dt[, unlist(strsplit(CLOB, "\r\n")), by = .(ID, DEVICE, METHOD)][
  ,DTTM:=str_extract(V1, "\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}")
][, VALUE := str_extract(V1, "](.*)", group = 1)][]
#>        ID DEVICE METHOD                          V1                DTTM  VALUE
#>     <num>  <num>  <num>                      <char>              <char> <char>
#>  1:     1     50     12 [02.01.2024 07:39:30]144,00 02.01.2024 07:39:30 144,00
#>  2:     1     50     12 [02.01.2024 07:41:30]146,00 02.01.2024 07:41:30 146,00
#>  3:     1     50     12 [02.01.2024 07:44:00]142,00 02.01.2024 07:44:00 142,00
#>  4:     1     50     12 [02.01.2024 07:49:00]167,00 02.01.2024 07:49:00 167,00
#>  5:     1     50     12 [02.01.2024 07:39:30]144,00 02.01.2024 07:39:30 144,00
#>  6:     1     50     12 [02.01.2024 07:41:30]146,00 02.01.2024 07:41:30 146,00
#>  7:     1     50     12 [02.01.2024 07:44:00]142,00 02.01.2024 07:44:00 142,00
#>  8:     1     50     12 [02.01.2024 07:49:00]167,00 02.01.2024 07:49:00 167,00
#>  9:     2     50     12 [02.01.2024 09:06:14]105,00 02.01.2024 09:06:14 105,00
#> 10:     2     50     12 [02.01.2024 09:07:44]107,00 02.01.2024 09:07:44 107,00
#> 11:     2     50     12  [02.01.2024 09:09:44]71,00 02.01.2024 09:09:44  71,00
#> 12:     2     50     12  [02.01.2024 09:11:44]86,00 02.01.2024 09:11:44  86,00


Thanks for all the answers. I chose this one since it introduces the fewest changes to my original code.

You can try reframe with dplyr
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  reframe(Extr = unlist(strsplit(CLOB, "\r\n")), 
          DTTM = str_extract(Extr, 
                   "\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}"), 
          VALUE = str_extract(Extr, "](.*)", group = 1), 
          .by = c(ID, DEVICE, METHOD)) %>% 
  select(-Extr)
# A tibble: 8 × 5
     ID DEVICE METHOD DTTM                VALUE 
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>               <chr> 
1     1     50     12 02.01.2024 07:39:30 144,00
2     1     50     12 02.01.2024 07:41:30 146,00
3     1     50     12 02.01.2024 07:44:00 142,00
4     1     50     12 02.01.2024 07:49:00 167,00
5     2     50     12 02.01.2024 09:06:14 105,00
6     2     50     12 02.01.2024 09:07:44 107,00
7     2     50     12 02.01.2024 09:09:44 71,00 
8     2     50     12 02.01.2024 09:11:44 86,00

Also try sub instead str_extract, using one less library and might give a slight speed up on huge data sets
df %>% 
  reframe(Extr = unlist(strsplit(CLOB, "\r\n")), 
          DTTM = sub(".*\\[(.*)\\].*", "\\1", Extr), 
          VALUE = sub(".*\\]", "", Extr), .by = c(ID, DEVICE, METHOD)) %>% 
  select(-Extr)
# A tibble: 8 × 5
     ID DEVICE METHOD DTTM                VALUE 
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>               <chr> 
1     1     50     12 02.01.2024 07:39:30 144,00
2     1     50     12 02.01.2024 07:41:30 146,00
3     1     50     12 02.01.2024 07:44:00 142,00
4     1     50     12 02.01.2024 07:49:00 167,00
5     2     50     12 02.01.2024 09:06:14 105,00
6     2     50     12 02.01.2024 09:07:44 107,00
7     2     50     12 02.01.2024 09:09:44 71,00 
8     2     50     12 02.01.2024 09:11:44 86,00


The following firstly ensures your ID number is unique by assigning it to the row number.  Then (1) calls strsplit to assign the results to a list object of equal length to your data table and (2) unnests those values according to your requirements.
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[,
   ID:=.I]
dt[,
   CLOB:=strsplit(CLOB, "\r\n")]

dt <- dt[,
         .(V1=unlist(CLOB,recursive=FALSE)),
         by = .(ID, DEVICE, METHOD)]

dt[, DTTM:=str_extract(V1, "\\d{2}.\\d{2}.\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}")]
dt[, VALUE:=str_extract(V1, "](.*)", group = 1)]


library(data.table)
dt[,unlist(tstrsplit(CLOB, "\r\n")), .(ID, DEVICE, METHOD)
  ][,c('V1', 'V2') := tstrsplit(sub('\\[', '', V1), '\\]')][]

      ID DEVICE METHOD                  V1     V2
   <num>  <num>  <num>              <char> <char>
1:     1     50     12 02.01.2024 07:39:30 144,00
2:     1     50     12 02.01.2024 07:41:30 146,00
3:     1     50     12 02.01.2024 07:44:00 142,00
4:     1     50     12 02.01.2024 07:49:00 167,00
5:     2     50     12 02.01.2024 09:06:14 105,00
6:     2     50     12 02.01.2024 09:07:44 107,00
7:     2     50     12 02.01.2024 09:09:44  71,00
8:     2     50     12 02.01.2024 09:11:44  86,00

